# How can I dispatch an event with an argument to jQuery.on() using plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event listener setup using jQuery like this:

```
$(document).on('my-custom-event', function(e, custom_id) {
  console.log('the ID is: ' + custom_id);
});
```

It is easy to trigger this with jQuery.trigger, like this:

```
$(document).trigger('my-custom-event', '12345');
```

But I am trying to figure out how to trigger it with vanilla javascript, and also ensure that `custom_id` gets passed properly.

For example, this does not work. It triggers the event, but does not pass the custom_id argument:

```
var e = new CustomEvent('my-custom-event', 'asdf')
document.dispatchEvent(e)
```

How can I use plain javascript to trigger the event and also pass the custom_id argument?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to pass extra param.. but it is possible to do something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7rydsyb2/1/

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent#Attributes), `detail` can be used to pass data when initializing the event.

Here is an example:

```
// add listener
// let's be cool and add it to the document for this example
document.addEventListener('EVENT-NAME', function (e) {
    // do something
    // use e.detail for the data
});

// create event
var event = new CustomEvent('EVENT-NAME', {
        detail: 'legit data'
});

// dispatch event
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I have also created a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/02p2o7ut/1/

Hopefully this helps and let me know if you have any other questions!

---

### EDIT:

Unfortunately, there is no way (that I know of) to do what you are asking, however, there is a workaround.

jQuery events have a property called `originalEvent`.  You could check to see if that value exists in the event that `custom_id` does not.  Here is how you could do this:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/02p2o7ut/2/

```
$(document).on('my-custom-event', function (e, custom_id) {
    // if custom_id not defined, will check e.originalEvent.detail
    custom_id = custom_id || e.originalEvent.detail;

    console.log('the ID is: ' + custom_id);
});

// trigger jQuery event
$(document).trigger('my-custom-event', '12345');


$('#customEvent').click(function () {
    // create event
    var event = new CustomEvent('my-custom-event', { detail: '12345' });

    // dispatch event
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am working in a system where the jQuery listener is already defined, and I'm trying to write vanilla javascript that can utilize it. So unfortunately this does not help, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Do you want that jQuery listener to dispatch the custom event?

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you're saying. I'll try a couple things.

Comment: @cilphex edited the post. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Unfortunately the listener is already setup and I cannot edit it, have to figure out a way to use vanilla js to send the custom_id to the listener as it is already written. I think it is impossible, so I simply cannot build the feature.